# Eclipse Kepler JDT content assist dreadfully slow on MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, content-assist

Running on MacOS using Kepler (4.3.1) and Java Proposals are dreadfully long, hanging the UI whenever I mistype something. This activity seems to cause serious Disk I/O:

```
Call graph:
    565 Thread_1045514   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 181 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1d91]
    + 133 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1d2c]
    + 81 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1d27]
    + 56 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1cf4]
    + 55 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1cc3]
    + 9 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1d8a]
    + 6 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1d1d]
    + 6 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1d59]
    + 6 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1d93]
    + 4 ???  (in )  [0x1069d1dca]
    + 3 ???  (in )  [0x106508c94]
    + ! 3 ???  (in )  [0x1067e05fc]
    + !   2 Java_java_io_UnixFileSystem_getBooleanAttributes0  (in libjava.dylib) + 86  [0x10059c51a]
    + !   : 1 JNU_GetStringPlatformChars  (in libjava.dylib) + 1163  [0x1005995e2]
    + !   : | 1 jni_CallObjectMethod  (in libjvm.dylib) + 278  [0x105cda1c6]
    + !   : |   1 jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)  (in libjvm.dylib) + 698  [0x105ce8605]
    + !   : |     1 JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)  (in libjvm.dylib) + 40  [0x105cb4b60]
    + !   : |       1 JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)  (in libjvm.dylib) + 401  [0x105cb4cf7]
    + !   : |         1 os::stack_shadow_pages_available(Thread*, methodHandle)  (in libjvm.dylib) + 1  [0x105df2a67]
    + !   : 1 JNU_GetStringPlatformChars  (in libjava.dylib) + 1352  [0x10059969f]
    + !   :   1 jni_GetByteArrayRegion  (in libjvm.dylib) + 127  [0x105ce4b37]
    + !   1 Java_java_io_UnixFileSystem_getBooleanAttributes0  (in libjava.dylib) + 109  [0x10059c531]
    + !     1 stat$INODE64  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff83301dfa]
```

I've increased my memory to 2G, but the heap display never goes beyond 350M. I occasionally get the "your results took too long" dialoging seen in some content assist activities.  Are my indexes corrupt?  Any thoughts on how I can get content assist back to normal?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but did this just start happening or has it always been that way since you installed Kepler SR1? It might be worth reinstalling it or installing a copy in another directory to see whether it still occurs. (Or maybe creating a new workspace??)

Comment: I remember after I switched to Kepler it ran fine until roughly December. I have tried a new Eclipse install and a new workspace (importing all my projects), but no change in behavior. The heavy disk I/O was also happening during cut/paste (causing Eclipse to hang), but disabling hyperlinking fixed that. I miss hyperlinking...

Comment: That definitely sucks. The only thing I can think of is going back to 4.3 or 4.2.2 (or trying a 4.4 milestone build?), and reporting it as a bug against eclipse. Good luck.

Comment: I'm definitely going to have to report a bug, but I don't know against what since the problem happens against 4.4M1, 4.3.1, 4.2 - and it varies what causes it. Sometimes hyperlinking and sometimes (mostly) content assist. All memory snapshots show the same filesystem IO as above.